# lxc-start:No container config specified

Tags: lxc, lxd

Installed the lxc container via lxc-create:

```
sudo lxc-create -t download -n dos1
```

I chose debian buster arm64 and run it:

```
sudo lxc-start -n dos1 -d
```

Outputs an error:

```
lxc-start: dos1: tools/lxc_start.c: main: 290 No container config specified
```

What is the problem? Am I doing something wrong?
PS: configs are configured /etc/lxc/default.conf:

```
lxc.net.0.type = veth
lxc.net.0.link = virbr0
lxc.net.0.flags = up

lxc.apparmor.profile = generated
lxc.apparmor.allow_nesting = 1
```

~/.config/lxc/default.conf:

```
lxc.net.0.type = veth
lxc.net.0.link = lxcbr0
lxc.net.0.flags = up

lxc.apparmor.profile = generated
lxc.apparmor.allow_nesting = 1

lxc.idmap = u 0 100000 65536
lxc.idmap = g 0 100000 65536
```

UPD
The problem is solved. You had to specify the path to the configuration file directly. For example:

```
sudo lxc-start -n dos1 -f /var/lib/lxc/dos1/config -d
```

Then all lxc-* commands must be executed with sudo

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I didn’t specify `sudo`. Without root permissions, `lxc-start` couldn’t find and read the container config to start it.

Answer (score 0):

Applying `sudo` depends on which type of **LXC** container you are working on.

Privileged containers require `sudo`, and must be created with `sudo create ...`.

Unprivileged containers though can be created with simply `lxc-create ...`